# CkEditor Doesn't post value

Tags: ajax, ckeditor

When a form with a textarea using CkEditor is submitted using ajax the post is empty on the server side.

If I remove CkEditor, the value is posted. Any ideas?

Comment: If by ajax you mean that your not using postback and only callback, then CKEditor will not update the underlaying element unless told to.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On submit, run this code:

```
for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

.. basically for AJAX, you need to force CKEditor to update your textareas so they contain the data you see in the CKEditor windows. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256510/how-to-ajax-submit-a-form-textarea-input-from-ckeditor) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to update anything with JS. All you have to do is to make sure your textarea (the one you replace with `CKEDITOR.replace()` on `$(document).ready()`) has the same name as the property you want to set value of, e.g.:

```
<textarea id="editor" name="Body">@Model?.Body</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' );
  function updateAllMessageForms()
   {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
          CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
   }
  }
```