# CKEDITOR doesn't submit data via ajax on first submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

My forms are not sending data to the server on the first submit when using CKEDITOR. If I click it once, it sends empty fields without my input. However, if I submit it a second time, it sends the inputted data to the server. So you need to submit it twice for data to be passed to the server.

I have CKEDITOR bundled with the BBCODE plugin.

#### jQuery Ajax

```
$('form#ajax').on('submit', function(){

    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
    });

    console.log(data.message); // Outputs on second submit

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response){

            //

        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

### Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'AppsController@sendApp', 'class' => 'app', 'id' => 'ajax')) }}

    <div class="form-container">

        {{ Form::label('message', 'Application', array('style' => 'padding-top: 5px')) }}

            <textarea name="message" cols="50" rows="6" class="form-control" id="eitor" style="padding-top:5px;"></textarea>


    </div>

        {{ Form::submit('Send Application', array('class' => 'btn btn-core btn-block submit', 'style' => 'margin-top: 5px')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Sorry if the form syntax looks alien to you, it's Laravel Blade.

### Recap

On first submit, the data sent to the server is empty. On the second submit, it is not.

Comment: have you tried debugging the code using the browser's inspector? ctrl+shift+i con google chrome, go to Sources tab, press ctrl+o and open the file with your javascript, now put some breakpoints and inspect the values, you sould find the error there

Comment: Could you provide a link? I suspect this may have something to do with the form tag or action on the form.

Comment: @arieljuod I've already debugged the code, it doesn't show an error. An SO question is my last resort.

Comment: @LindyHop It has nothing to do with the action. I completely disabled the AJAX call and simply console logged the value of message and it returned empty first, then filled second.

Comment: This question (and answer) is similar to this one that was asked 3 years prior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256510/how-to-ajax-submit-a-form-textarea-input-from-ckeditor

Answer (score 47, accepted):

try updating the CKEditor related fields, before performing Ajax Submit, like:

```
$('form#ajax').on('submit', function(){
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
    //rest of your code
```

Comment: I totally forgot to come back to give you more rep. This worked :)

Comment: perfect thank you! =) took me a while to realize that the ajax submit stopped working because I just changed the plain textarea field to CKEditor..you saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: I had the same issue, and tried to use your solution in the `beforeSend` callback of the `$.ajax(` method but it didn't work (perhaps I just messed something up). Then I tried it as you suggest and it worked.

Comment: thank you, this really helped, I was wondering if you could explain why such kind of behavior happens?