# ckeditor won't post updated content

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor 4.6.2 and have come across a problem where if I change the contents in the editor, they are not being posted back to the server through an ajax call.

My set up is like this:

- Textarea with ID `#editor1` has ckeditor applied on it.
- On page load I use ajax to load some content in to the editor from a database (this all works fine).
- My submit button has the ID `#sendBtn`

I then use ajax to handle the form submission - pressing `#sendBtn`. The post works, but if I've edited the content in `#editor1` it submits the *original* content - what was there on page load, not the edited content.

I came cross this post [How to ajax-submit a form textarea input from CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256510/how-to-ajax-submit-a-form-textarea-input-from-ckeditor). I've added the accepted answer before my ajax call. So my jquery for handling submission looks like this:

```
$('#sendBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sendBtn').prop( "disabled", true);
    var dataString = $("#emailForm").serialize();

    /**
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256510/how-to-ajax-submit-a-form-textarea-input-from-ckeditor 
     */
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/ajax/email",
        data: dataString,
        method: "POST",
      }).done(function(data) {
          // ...
      });
});
```

If I use PHP to dump the POST data at `/admin/ajax/email` it is showing the original content, not the updated version.

What's strange is that if I run this in my browser console, it returns `true` and then things appear to work:

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
```

So is the issue that the above code isn't completing before the ajax call is made? How would I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

OK a bit late.

As your (very helpful) reference indicates, you must update the CKEDITOR instances **before** you touch the form, so:

```
$('#sendBtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sendBtn').prop( "disabled", true);

    // This before:
    for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();

    // Then this:
    var dataString = $("#emailForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin/ajax/email",
        data: dataString,
        method: "POST",
      }).done(function(data) {
          // ...
      });
});
```

Comment: I didn't require this code on my main form, but on another form which uses a Bootstrap modal it was the only thing that worked for me.